# Get folder with largest number at the end of the name in Linux

Tags: linux, shell-script

On Linux, I have some folders r1, r2, r3, etc. and I want to get the name of the folder with the largest number at the end. How do I get the name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
printf '%s\n' r[0-9]* | sort --version-sort | tail -n 1
```

Comment: Just for completeness: `--version-sort` doesn't exist on OS X (sort (GNU coreutils) 5.93)

Comment: @slhck: Well, the question specifically mentions Linux, and we have coreutils 8.11 here.

Comment: I know, that's why I said "just for completeness".

Answer (score 2):

My version of `ls` has `ls -v`

```
$ for i in {1..19}; do touch r$i; done
$ ls | tail -1
r9
$ ls -v | tail -1
r19
$ ls --version
ls (GNU coreutils) 8.10
```